# How to select keys in nested maps in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Let's say I have a map (`m`) like this:

```
(def m {:a 1 :b 2 :c {:d 3 :e 4} :e { ... } ....})
```

I'd like to create a new map only containing `:a`, `:b` and `:d` from `m`, i.e. the result should be:

```
{:a 1 :b 2 :d 3}
```

I know that I can use `select-keys` to easily get `:a` and `:b`:

```
(select-keys m [:a :b])
```

But what's a good way to also get `:d`? I'm looking for something like this:

```
(select-keys* m [:a :b [:c :d]])
```

Does such a function exists in Clojure or what's the recommended approach?

Comment: For complex nested data structure access, you'll be well served by something like specter  https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter

Comment: @sw1nn That was what I was thinking too, but can you come up with the specter solution?

Comment: I actually tried specter before writing the question but I couldn't find out how to do this. So a specter answer would be appreciated too :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In pure Clojure I would do it like this:

```
(defn select-keys* [m paths]
  (into {} (map (fn [p]
                  [(last p) (get-in m p)]))
        paths))

(select-keys* m [[:a] [:b] [:c :d]]) ;;=> {:a 1, :b 2, :d 3}
```

I prefer keeping the type of a path regular, so a sequence of keys for all paths. In `clojure.spec` this would read as

```
(s/def ::nested-map (s/map-of keyword? 
                              (s/or :num number? :map ::nested-map)))
(s/def ::path (s/coll-of keyword?))
(s/fdef select-keys*
        :args (s/cat :m ::nested-map 
                     :paths (s/coll-of ::path)))
```

Comment: If you require your paths to be vectors, then you can use `peek` instead of `last` and be much faster.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative you can use destructing on a function, for example:

```
(def m {:a 1 :b 2 :c {:d 3 :e 4}})

(defn get-m
  [{a :a b :b {d :d} :c}]
  {:a 1 :b b :d d})

(get-m m) ; => {:a 1, :b 2, :d 3}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of such a function being part of Clojure. You'll probably have to write it yourself. I've came up with this :

```
(defn select-keys* [m v]
  (reduce 
    (fn [aggregate next]
      (let [key-value (if (vector? next)
                        [(last next)
                         (get-in m next)]
                        [next
                         (get m next)])]
        (apply assoc aggregate key-value)))
    {}
    v))
```

Comment: To comply with select-keys fn, we can add 'if' on the return.

This way trying to get a key that doesn't exist won't result in nil, like in the original answer.

(defn select-keys* [m v]
  (reduce
    (fn [aggregate next]
      (let [key-value (if (vector? next)
                        [(last next)
                           (get-in m next)]
                        [next
                                  (get m next)]
                        )]
        (if (second key-value)
          (apply assoc aggregate key-value)
          aggregate)
        ))
    {}
    v))

Answer (score 3):

You can use [clojure.walk](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.walk-api.html).

```
(require '[clojure.walk :as w])

(defn nested-select-keys
  [map keyseq]
  (w/postwalk (fn [x]
                (if (map? x)
                  (select-keys x keyseq)
                  (identity x))) map))

(nested-select-keys {:a 1 :b {:c 2 :d 3}} [:a :b :c])
  ; => {:a 1, :b {:c 2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Require paths to be vectors so you can use `peek` (much faster than `last`).  Reduce over the paths like this:

```
(defn select-keys* [m paths] 
  (reduce (fn [r p] (assoc r (peek p) (get-in m p))) {} paths))

(select-keys* m [[:a] [:b] [:c :d]]) ;;=> {:a 1, :b 2, :d 3}
```

Of course, this assumes that all your terminal keys are unique.